# Are endorsed undergraduates eligible to submit papers (and eventually get it accepted) to arXiv?

Tags: arxiv

> Is it possible for an undergraduate to submit his first preprint to arXiv and get it accepted ? Assume that he/she has been endorsed.

I am asking this because so far the papers that I have observed the email id seemed to be email id of Professors of some university or colleges but of course it may not be the case in general.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'accepted'. As far as I know, the arXiv doesn't perform any quality control, other than the endorsement process.

Comment: "accepted" means to be available online as an arXiv paper.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. From the [explanation of the endrsement system](http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement): "Endorsement is a necessary but not sufficient condition to have papers accepted in arXiv; arXiv reserves the right to reject or reclassify any submission." Rejection seems to be quite rare and is based [almost exclusively on violations of the arXiv policy](http://arxiv.org/help/moderation), not the scientific merit of your submission.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, of course.  The arXiv staff doesn't sit around evaluating the credentials of everyone who submits.  They reserve the right to reject even endorsed submissions, but this is unusual.

The main obstacle to publishing on the arXiv as an undergraduate is writing a suitable paper and getting it endorsed.

Comment: Even if he/she has no previous publication record?

Comment: @user170039: Lack of previous publication record is one of the main things the endorsement system addresses.  It may mean that the paper will get more careful scrutiny to make sure it's not nonsense, but the academic status of the submitter has nothing to do with that.